# How to link database table with custom column name

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say i have a table "UserTable"

| ID | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | row |
| Second | row | row |

And i have a table "CustomColumnName"

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Username |
| 2 | Password |

I can then link the "CustomColumnName" as the column name to "UserTable" and the result will be

| ID | Username | Password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | row |
| Second | row | row |

The column name will change based on the "CustomColumnName".

Is it possible to do this with SQL? Or it must be done by programming.
Any idea? Thanks